# How to get elements using getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, nightmare

I'm using nightmareJS and was trying to webscrape by using document.getElementsByClassName, this is the code:

```
import Nightmare from 'nightmare'
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })
var name = name
nightmare
    .goto('https://www.amazon.com/')
    
    .insert("input[aria-label='Search']", 'impressora')
    .click("input[value='Go']")
    .wait(2000)
    
    .evaluate(function(){
        let text = document.getElementsByClassName('a-offscreen')[0];
        name = text;
        return name;
            
    }).then(function (name)  {
        console.log('Price:', name)
        
    });
```

[The code gets until here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPTXk.png)

The output is this:

```
Price: [object HTMLSpanElement]
```

What I would like to get is the price which is in the class "a-offscreen". Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: `return document.querySelector('.a-offscreen span').innerText;` (you're trying to print the element itself, not the text inside it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName(class);` returns a collection of elements having the queried class but not their content so you have to access `innerText` property of your element:

```js
let text = document.getElementsByClassName('a-offscreen')[0].innerText;
name = text;
return name;
```

The output would be:

```js
Price: $199.99
```